# Error with SAGA's Topgraphic Correction: Can't load requested DLL gdal_MrSID.dll

Tags: qgis, saga

I am using QGIS 2.14.2, trying to perform a supervised classification on a rapideye image with the SCP plugin.
To improve my classification im trying to work with the SAGA's topographic correction. I'm getting an error:

```
Algorithm Topographic correction starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\931e23b8ca264f28881245cf4907d809\mdesul8.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/mdesul8.tif"
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\bcc9b014bab349f487eda68bae9ad6da\sulbarbaraB1.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/sulbarbaraB1.tif"
ta_lighting "Topographic Correction" -DEM "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\931e23b8ca264f28881245cf4907d809\mdesul8.sgrd" -ORIGINAL "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\bcc9b014bab349f487eda68bae9ad6da\sulbarbaraB1.sgrd" -AZI 16 -HGT 46 -METHOD 4 -MINNAERT 0.5 -MAXCELLS 1000 -MAXVALUE 1 -CORRECTED "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\b69f195bca204e7781d392f9d18ffe9f\CORRECTED.sdat"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps\saga

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\grass\grass-7.0.3\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\grass\grass-7.0.3\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\WBem;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps\saga;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\931e23b8ca264f28881245cf4907d809\mdesul8.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/mdesul8.tif"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.


ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.


_____________________________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
_____________________________________________

_____________________________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\modules\io_gdal.dll
library name: Import/Export - GDAL/OGR
tool name : GDAL: Import Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
_____________________________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/mdesul8.tif"
Transformation: yes
Interpolation: Nearest Neighbor


loading: C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/mdesul8.tif



Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 7162

Columns: 5250



Transformation:

x' = 614095.102163 + x * 4.999971 + y * 0.000000

y' = 7217125.000000 + x * 0.000000 + y * -5.000000



warning: top-to-bottom and left-to-right cell sizes differ.
using cellsize: 4.999971

loading band [1/1]







C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\bcc9b014bab349f487eda68bae9ad6da\sulbarbaraB1.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/sulbarbaraB1.tif"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.


ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.


_____________________________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
_____________________________________________

_____________________________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\modules\io_gdal.dll
library name: Import/Export - GDAL/OGR
tool name : GDAL: Import Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
_____________________________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/sulbarbaraB1.tif"
Transformation: yes
Interpolation: Nearest Neighbor


loading: C:/Users/Guilherme/Desktop/TCC/teste plugin/sulbarbaraB1.tif



Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 7162

Columns: 5250



Transformation:

x' = 614095.102163 + x * 4.999971 + y * 0.000000

y' = 7217125.000000 + x * 0.000000 + y * -5.000000



warning: top-to-bottom and left-to-right cell sizes differ.
using cellsize: 4.999971

loading band [1/1]







C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>saga_cmd ta_lighting "Topographic Correction" -DEM "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\931e23b8ca264f28881245cf4907d809\mdesul8.sgrd" -ORIGINAL "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\bcc9b014bab349f487eda68bae9ad6da\sulbarbaraB1.sgrd" -AZI 16 -HGT 46 -METHOD 4 -MINNAERT 0.5 -MAXCELLS 1000 -MAXVALUE 1 -CORRECTED "C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\b69f195bca204e7781d392f9d18ffe9f\CORRECTED.sdat"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.


ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.


12:23:55: Error: XML parsing error: 'not well-formed (invalid token)' at line 11
_____________________________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
_____________________________________________

_____________________________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\modules\ta_lighting.dll
library name: Terrain Analysis - Lighting, Visibility
tool name : Topographic Correction
author : Copyrights (c) 2008 by Olaf Conrad
_____________________________________________

Load grid: C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\931e23b8ca264f28881245cf4907d809\mdesul8.sgrd...


Load grid: C:\Users\GUILHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing0150848eaebb4677b6913450d3dde9f6\bcc9b014bab349f487eda68bae9ad6da\sulbarbaraB1.sgrd...




Parameters


Grid system: 4.999971; 7163x 5251y; 614097.602149x 7190872.5y
Grid system: 4.999971; 7163x 5251y; 614097.602149x 7190872.5y
Elevation: mdesul8
Original Image: sulbarbaraB1
Corrected Image: Corrected Image
Azimuth: 16.000000
Height: 46.000000
Method: Minnaert Correction with Slope (Law & Nichol 2004)
Minnaert Correction: 0.500000
Maximum Cells (C Correction Analysis): 1000
Value Range: 2 byte (0-65535)

Illumination calculation







C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin>exit
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
```

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Corrected Image
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Comment: Does C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\saga\modules\io_gdal.dll
 exist ? Do any over SAGA algorithms work? 
 https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/support-requests/9/ could help